# Jquery Onclick button is working only once

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

On click button, it's working fine for the first time but when I click again it's not working...

```js
$(document).on('click', '#btn', function(){
  $( "#response").html('GOOD').fadeOut(2000)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="response"></div>
<button id="btn">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Don't just write _"it's not working..."_ but explain what happens, what should happen, are there any errors.

Comment: because it is hidden. You are hiding something that is hidden.

Comment: [`.fadeOut()`](https://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/): _"Hide the matched elements by fading them to transparent."_

Comment: I want to show #response each time I click on #btn and fade out after 2 seconds

Comment: *"I want to show #response each time"* <-- so "show()" it. You have he answer right in front of you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it will be work for u

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="response"></div>
 <button id="btn">Click Me</button>
   <script>
    $(document).on('click', '#btn', function(){
    $("#response").show().html('GOOD').fadeOut(2000);
    
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are hiding an element. First time it is visible and it hides. Second time it is hidden and hides. You need to show it.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="response"></div>
<button id="btn">Click Me</button>
<script>
  $(document).on('click', '#btn', function() {
    $("#response").html('GOOD').show().fadeOut(2000);
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You never `fadeIn` the `div`, so it remains hidden. Which is why the button only works once.